# Active MQ load balancing to achieve high throughput

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Currently my activeMQ configuration (non persistent messaging) allows me to achieve 2000 msgs/sec. There are four queues and four consumers consuming the messages. There's only one activeMQ broker in this configuration. I would like to achieve a higher throughput of about 5000 msgs/sec (with addition of additional brokers). I'm pretty clueless on how to achieve this with out splitting individual queues on to individual ActiveMQ instances. What are the topologies that support higher throughput than the individual instance with out splitting the queues among instances ?

Comment: How do you manage transactions? What's the size of the messages? Can you group some messages logically together in a single message? How many *threads* are sending, how many are receiving?

Comment: We don't need transactions, fire and forget type messaging. typical messages payload is about 1K. there are about 10 agents sending while only 4 threads receiving in total. Grouping messages requires code amends which is not possible. Looking in to any configuration and/or topology changes

Comment: What about adding a cluster of brokers ? see http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html and http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

Comment: Are you able to receive messages concurrently? Then you probably just want to add more consumer threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a network of brokers *might* help. That is if you have a decent number of consumers and a decent number of producers connecting to different brokers.

If you have a single producer or a single consumer, all traffic will still go over one of the brokers, making it the bottleneck in any case. So, your actual setup of the servers using the AMQ broker is important.

You will also need to check what's the bottleneck of your physical machines. Is it I/O?  CPU? Memory usage/heap size? Even Linkspeed? Use OS tools together with visualvm to track this down. Then you at least know what kind of server you need next.

In any case, some semi-manual load balancing is always possible over several nodes, weather you are using a network of brokers or not. Just make sure messages are routed through certain brokers depending on their content or whatnot. If you cannot distinguish between different message types in any logical way - you can do things like finding some integer number in the message (be it client IP, yesterdays temperature in celsius or whatever), and do a `number modulo <num brokers>`. Then route it to the destination you selected. Round robin is also an option. There is almost always a way to distribute the load in a logical way among several brokers.